# How to use Blender to get model to a state where it can be shrank with gltfjsx

Tags: texturing, gltf

I'm fairly new to Blender (and trying to understand how to use 3d tooling in general), so this question is coming from still trying to 'map out the landscape' to use a visual analogy.

I'm trying to run this command:
`npx gltfjsx ./myfile.gltf --types --shadows --transform --aggressive --draco https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.1/`

which usually compresses files with no issues..

If these files are scans generated by lidar scan, (or the other algorithmic method which uses photos, for which I forget the name), I get this error:
`Error: maxMemoryUsageInMB limit exceeded by at least 225MB`

I thought for a while that it was because these methods produce a lot of polgyons, but after a bit of research, I'm wondering if it is because of the texture sizes, and whether or not it is possible to shrink them (https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/issues/344)

Would really appreciate knowing if I'm following the right lead here, and if so, where would be good to read next.

Thanks

Comment: I'm struggling to work out what this has to do with Blender!

Comment: Maybe I need to move the question to a different stack exchange community. I know blender can probably be used to reduce texture sizes, but I'm not sure if that is something which causes an 'unpegging' with the polygons (or is that just when merging polygons?) Ideally, if someone knew what I need to google in order to figure out how to change texture sizes (and indeed if this is the the right way to go about this), then this would be ideal. Thanks for the help @JohnEason

Comment: I've posted an update on [glTF-Transform#344](https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/issues/344) you can reply there if you like. GitHub discussions for glTF-Transform or GLTFJSX might also be good options. The limitation here is indeed the size of the textures. Blender _can_ resize textures, but may not be the easiest way to go about this.

Comment: Thanks again @DonMcCurdy, saving as a non-embedded gltf and resizing manually should have been something I thought of, seems so obvious now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @donmccurdy for the help with this (https://github.com/donmccurdy/glTF-Transform/issues/344).
Steps are as follows:

- Use blender to save a HUGE gltf as a 'separate' file (so the texture is separate).
- Use Photoshop/Gimp to resize the texture.
- Re-import into blender
- Export again as an embedded gltf
- Run npx gltfjsx ./myfile.gltf --types --shadows --transform --aggressive --draco https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.4.1/ to squish it into a nicely sized glb file

(When you do 5., the tsx generated might include a . in the file name, so either rename them in blender in step 3., or write typescript like so in the generated tsx):

````
type GLTFResult = GLTF & {
  nodes: {
    Mesh_0001: THREE.Mesh
  }
  materials: {
    'material_0.001': THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
  }
}

<mesh castShadow receiveShadow geometry={nodes.Mesh_0001.geometry} material={materials['material_0.001']} />
```
````